# jdbc connection to Mysql outside of VPN

Tags: mysql, jdbc, vpn

I have a public accessible Mysql instance and i am trying to access it behind a clients VPN. So, on the VPN I was granted access to the DB, so by doing
`mysql -h IP -u user -p`
I can connect to it and run queries just fine 
The problems start when I try to connect to it via a CLI java application.
I open the connection like so

```
Connection source= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+getHost()+"/"+getDB()+"?useUnicode=true",
            getUser(),getPass());
```

and I get no errors.
when i try to run a query like so

```
rs=source.createStatement().executeQuery("select ...");
```

I am getting nothing. I have been sitting there waiting and no results comes back nor an error/exception!

The Mysql instance is accepting the connection since I can see the connection when i get the processlist

> +----+------+-----+----+---------------+------+--------+------+
>   | Id | User | Host| db | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
>   +----+------+-----+----+---------------+------+--------+------+
>   | 9094 | user |ClientIp:58450 | DB | Sleep   | 4933 |          | NULL 
>   |

plus when i get the error log of the db

> tail /var/log/mysql/error.log 2019-04-23T14:17:34.286979Z 9175 [Note]
>   Aborted connection 9175 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host:
>   'ClientIp' (Got an error reading
>   communication packets) 2019-04-23T14:17:46.501602Z 9174 [Note] Aborted
>   connection 9174 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host:
>   'ClientIp' (Got timeout writing
>   communication packets)

I am starting to think that they network guys on the client side, open up the outgoing ports (3306, so i can connect to the DB) but the incoming port (which is random as far as I know and remember from my college network cource). This must be confirmed by the host record of process list which is `IP:58450`. This is the listening port of the client, right. So if this is closed the connection would stay open, waiting for an incoming message, but the message itself would be blocked(since the port is blocked)
First, is there a way to validate this so I can know for sure that this is the problem with this? Just to have something to talk to the network people over there.

From what i know, you cant specify a (range of) port for the client to talk to. What can you do in cases where ports are blocked by firewalls?

Thanks in advance. Ilias

---

**UPDATE**
When running netstat while connected to Mysql I see this

> netstat -a |grep mysql
>   tcp       0      0 client:58744 MySqlRemote.e:mysql ESTABLISHED

while when I connect using java I get

> tcp6       0      0 client:58748 MySqlRemote.e:mysql ESTABLISHED

so, it seems that the connection is ok in both cases. The only obvious difference is tcp - tcp6 on the two records. So I thought that the problem might be on using IP6 in java. I tried to disable it by using
        `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");`
and disabling IP6 on the VM alltogether by editing the `/etc/hosts` file.
The result is that now using netstat i see IP4 is been used, but the query is still not responding.

Comment: So you can *connect* using the `mysql` client from a command prompt, but can you also run queries on that connection?

Comment: @GordThompson yes, I thought this was implied. will update the question

Comment: When I run Wireshark on the client I just see a conversation between port 49446 on the client and port 3306 on the server. But then again, I am able to run queries on that (direct JDBC) connection. And even if your server is trying to start a conversation from some other server port it would be the server who initiates the conversation so the VPN/firewall should implicitly open that port for you. Are you by chance doing anything like streaming results or otherwise using `setFetchSize` to override the default behaviour of retrieving a result set?

Comment: @GordThompson I am not doing anything out of the ordinary. I use PrepareStatements and Resultset to write and read. I am not familiar with Wireshark, I see it is only available for Win and Mac, we are using Linux. Will try to install it from source, will search for linux alternatives as well. 
If the VPN has all ports blocked, will a request from a confirmed server can open that port? Will have to talk to their network ppl. :(